# Force close chrome extension popup from background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I have a background script and I am trying to force close the extension popup programmatically from the background script.

I tried doing

`window.close();`

Which won't work since that would have to be ran from an extension page not a background script.

Then I tried doing

`chrome.tabs.update({ active: true });`

which is supposed to switch the focus to the current tab which should then close the extension window, but that does not seem to work either.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [chrome.extension.getViews](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews) to close all opened popups:

```js
chrome.extension.getViews({type: 'popup'}).forEach(v => v.close());
```

...or just the one in the focused window:

```js
chrome.windows.getLastFocused(w => {
  chrome.extension.getViews({type: 'popup', windowId: w.id}).forEach(v => v.close());
});
```

Alternatively you can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) via chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send a message like 'closePopup' so the popup receives it and closes itself using window.close() in its onMessage handler.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this was exactly the info I needed. Thanks so much =]